# How to flip specific points to the opposite side of the plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to flip the points on the left side of the graph to lay over points on the right side of the graph. But I unfortunately am not sure how to do this.

Any point that lies between 0 and 49 on the x axis I would like to flip so that those points are now on the 50 - 100 side of the x axis

My plot now:

```
ggplot(shotchart, aes(x=as.numeric(V1), y=as.numeric(V2))) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = class, shape = shot_type ), size = 4) +
xlim(-1, 102) +
ylim(102, -3) +
geom_rug(alpha = .2) +
coord_fixed()
```

What my plot looks like:

[image]

Any help with this will be appreciated. Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Comment: You may redefine the x coordinate of those point with x<50 to 100 - x. 
If you then run the code for the plot you should have the desired effect.

Comment: `ifelse(x < 50, 100 - x, x)` directly in the aes should work too

Comment: One more quick fix: `x= abs(as.numeric(V1) -50) + 50`